# Insert image to EGOTextView

Tags: ios, image, rich-text-editor

I have downloded an EGOTextView Demo.And do some rich editor with it.Now the question is that how can I insert an image into it??
Anyone ?

Comment: This is an interesting question, would love to see the answer

Answer (score 0):

[There](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView/issues/17)  is some description how to add image to EGOTextView, but it is not fully describe solution